# how to extract information from Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) with a SQL query

Tags: sql, windows, shared-libraries

I've never used WSUS and I'm no sql expert, so I don't really know how to get the correct data. The goal is to create an excel that contains these columns for each pc:

Name

IPAddress

LastReportedStatusTime

Model

OS

OSBuildNumber

GroupName

Location

Unknown

NotInstalled

Downloaded

Installed

Failed

InstalledPendingReboot

SupportStatusMicrosoft

OSFamily

OSDescription

Can anyone help me understand where this information resides and how I can extract it with a sql query?
This information I know was obtained in the past with sql queries.

I tried a few queries but not knowing where the data I'm looking for is difficult for me to get a usable result